# Laravel Feature testing, how do i test if a profile page has been created with the user?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I created my feature test;

##### `ProfilesControllerTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProfileControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_the_profile_page_is_rendered()
    {
        // First The user is created
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        //act as user
        $this->actingAs($user);

        // Then we want to make sure a profile page is created
        $response = $this->get('/profile/{user}');

        //
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

##### `web.php`

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profiles.show');
```

But it keeps returning an error. I Suspect it is because of the profile link, however I am unsure of how to show it. I have attempted a few variations and i have not managed to get it to work.

I realised factory was not working so instead I tried this;

##### `ProfilesControllerTest.php`

```
public function test_the_profile_page_is_rendered()
{
    // First The user is created
    $user = User::make([
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'username' => 'johnnyd',
        'email' => 'johndoe@email.com'
    ]);

    //act as user
    $this->actingAs($user);

    // Then we want to make sure a profile page is created
    $response = $this->get('/profile/{$user}');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

And I kept getting the error:

##### Error

```
php artisan test

 PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
✓ basic test

 PASS  Tests\Unit\UserTest
✓ login form
✓ user duplication

 PASS  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
✓ basic test

 FAIL  Tests\Feature\ProfileControllerTest
✕ the profile page is rendered

Tests:  1 failed, 4 passed, 1 pending

Expected status code 200 but received 404. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

at tests/Feature/ProfileControllerTest.php:34
  30|         // Then we want to make sure a profile page is created
  31|         $response = $this->get('/profile/{$user');
  32| 
  33|         //

> 34|         $response->assertStatus(200);
  35|     }
  36| }
  37|
```

Profile controller for index was written as follows:

##### `ProfilesController.php`

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $postCount = Cache::remember(
            'count.posts.' . $user->id,
            now()->addSeconds(30),
            function () use ($user) {
                return $user->posts->count();
            }
        );

        return view('profiles.index', compact('user', 'postCount'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that `/profile/{user}` is a valid URL. How about `/profile/$user->id`?

Comment: @miken32 just tried that, still recieving a 404 error. Just tried to make a user with an id set as 1 and passed that in, and it still is not working.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Your error message there should be quite clear; it also doesn't match any of the code you've provided.

Comment: Also /profile/{user} is a valid URL. When navigating to the page it works and previews as /profile/1 @miken32

Comment: You're confusing a route definition with a URL.

Comment: First of all, your test URL should be `/profile/{$user->id}`, second, share your controller code.

Comment: I shared my controller code earlier, it got edited out it seems. And yeah i have been writing it with $user->id

Comment: You understand that putting a variable in single quotes doesn't expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first test isn't working because you're attempting to access the wrong URL. You're attempting to go to `http://localhost/profile/{user}`. That URL is not correct, as there is no user with an id of "{user}". The URL you want to access is `http://localhost/profile/1`, to see the profile of the user with id `1`.

To fix the first test, fix the URL:

```
// bad
// $response = $this->get('/profile/{user}');

// good
$response = $this->get('/profile/'.$user->id);
```

Your second test is failing for two reasons:

1. `User::make()` will make a new instance of the `User` model, but it will not persist anything to the database. Since the `User` won't exist in the database, it does not have a profile URL you can visit.
2. Again, as in the first test, the profile URL you're trying to visit is wrong.

So, go back to the first test, correct the URL, and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you! $response = $this->get('/profile/'.$user->id); worked perfectly. I completly disregarded the use of (.). Much appreciated